# Why does google chrome does not open a custom URL whereas Internet Explorer can?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, url, custom-url

I registered a custom URL using this program https://customurl.codeplex.com/.
I mapped a custom URL to a VB exe program that I created. After this, this custom URL only works with Internet explorer, but it does not work in Google Chrome. I searched all over but can't find any answer to this weird situation.

Thanks,